# Xceed Zip for .NET Compact Framework v2.1 on CF2

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, zip, xceed

I have been using Xceed Zip for .NET Compact Framework v2.1 for years with VS 2003. On Windows Mobile 6.1 devices xceed.zip gives a System.TypeLoadException.

Trying the same component with VS2008 again results in the below exception. It seems as if it is trying to work with CF1 on a CF2 device.

System.TypeLoadException: File or assembly name 'System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089', or one of its dependencies, was not found. at Xceed.Zip.QuickZip.Zip()

Anyone with a solution? (Please don't tell me to buy a newer version)

Answer (score 0):

B77A5C561934E089 is the public token for the full framework.  You have a reference somewhere in your solution to a full framework assembly and that's why it doesn't want to run.